# Date Conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, time, sql-server-2014

I have a date in following format in my DB.

`10/16` - `mm/yy`

I need to convert it to:

`October/16`

Is this possible?

If it's not possible then please tell me why.

Comment: Perhaps knowing the database will help us!

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I am usig SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Why are your dates stored as strings?  And why do you want to transform from one string to another?  Why not just use a native DATE datatype?

Comment: Yes I am using string format, because all the data are imported from old DB. we need format unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a date, it's missing the day, it's a bad way to store year/month. There should be a 4 digit year to avoid confusion and the year should be listed first to enable correct sorting, e.g. `'2016/10'` or a numeric value `201610`.

You can cast it to a DATE first and then use a FORMAT to disply only month/year:

```
set dateformat myd;
select format(cast(mystupidcolumn + '/1' as date), 'MMMM/yy')
```

Or SUBSTR the month part and use a CASE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and it depend in what database you use to call date functions 
If you column Datetime format

- SQL server `DATENAME(Month, GETDATE())`
- MySQL database `MONTHNAME(now())`

otherwise 
 convert it will in your choice at database or you code logic 
   split the value and lookup at month `enum` or fake the date to be accepted and complete date format like `01/10/16`

so do something like `SELECT  DATENAME(Month, datecolumn) + '/' + YEAR (datecolumn)`

also you can use instead of `Year` function `DATEPART(yy,datecolumn)`
the way you do it with format will look like 
`CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)` 
but excepted to get first 3 char of month `JUN`

Comment: I updated the answer hope this help more, noteice that not using date format function

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  I think this error for date format having only two parts.

Comment: Is the date type for this column date time, I think of it is not, I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Yeah, The column is nvarchar.

Comment: concatenate day to it like so `1/10/16` for your column before you convert it to date time, but what I think of your database is kind of `2016-06-16`

Answer (score 0):

try this format,

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @mydate-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display date by using this code

```
select datename(month, YourColumnName) + '/' + right(YEAR(YourColumnName),2) 
FROM   yourTableName
```

Simply change `yourColumnName` with name of your table column and `yourTableName` with name of table.

Comment: I get this Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error..